# Calculate chi-square statistics in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, chi-squared

I'd like to calculate chi-square statistics in R, which is defined as

sum[(O_i-E_i)^2/E_i], where O_i and E_i are the probability masses in category i.

But the problem is I only have empirical cumulative distribution for a variable. Say I have a vector, and I can calculate its empirical cumulative distribution, and I also have a predicted cumulative distribution. So in R, how can I calculate chi-square statistics by using these two cumulative probability?

For example, below is the code I use,

```
require(VGAM)
X <- rpareto(100,1.5,2.5)
# Empricial distribution of X, P is the true probability
P <- ecdf(X)

#MLEs
scale <- min(X)
shape <- length(X)/sum(log(X/scale))
estimated_prob <- ppareto(X,scale,shape)
```

I first simulate 100 values distributed pareto, and then calculate MLEs, so I have the true data and predicted distribution.

Comment: Something like http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/chi-squared-test-independence ?

Comment: This looks promising, thanks. But the problem is, I do not have such two variables but instead have two probability distribution for a single variable. In that case, how to do that

Comment: Would you not rather do the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test? If so, use `ks.test` from the `stats` package. Perhaps Cross-Validated is a better forum for this question?

Comment: On CrossValidated.com it would be a duplicate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78168/how-to-know-if-my-data-fits-pareto-distribution/78174#78174  Chi-squared tests are designed for discrete distributions while the Pareto distrib is continuous..

Answer (score 0):

(Offered as an example of why NOT to use chi-squared test for this question. And see the CrossValidated.com answer that I referenced in my earlier comment.) The `estimated_prob` and the results from the ECDF are "pretty darned close" as one might expect looking at the setup of the problem. Look at both this plot:

```
 plot( P(X), estimated_prob )
```

[image]

Why is this so close to a straight line? The estimated_prob is the theoretical probability that X_hat (and here I'm using the simulated `X` values you created as one possible instance) is less then a random variable, X, in a Pareto distribution while the `P(X)` is the actual fraction (i.e probability) that an item in that sample is less than X. Since `P` is a function, we need to use the form `P(X)` to get a `numeric` result in the R language.

Since the Pareto distribution is continuous, any arbitrary binning of the values in 2, 3 10 or 20 boxes in order get a chisquare statistic will be a relatively imprecise and arbitrary method of assessing "goodness of fit". Who's to say what the "right" number of bins really should be? There is a very welll-considered R package named `fitdistrplus` that you might want to review and work through its vignettes.

Comment: Yes, and hence my suggestion for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but he should post to Cross Validated as there are more people like yourself there to help him.

Comment: IMO, the comment-cited answer on CV.com was already present and didn't want to encourage duplicates on CV, and the only thing remaining was demonstrating how the R `ecdf` function was delivering the result that was needed to use the KS test. I thought of that as more R-specific and something that was therefore appropriate for SO.